# In self invoking function expression (closures) , result is same always

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a self invoking function Expression in a ajax call

```
$("#helpicons li").click(function () {
 var self = this;

 $.post('/SubCategories/GetSubCat/' + $(self).data('id'), function (data)
 {

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
      var helplist = data[i];

          $('<li/>').html("<h5>" + helplist.scat + "</h5>" +"<ul id='qlist'></ul>").appendTo('#taglist');



      $.post('/Questions/GetQuestion/' + helplist.scatid, function (dd)
      {
          for (var j = 0; j < dd.length; j++)
          {
              var helpquestion = dd[j];

              (function () {

                  $('<li/>').html("<p>" + helpquestion.quest + "</p>")
                  .click(function () {

                      alert(helpquestion.quest);//Problem is here

                  }).appendTo('#qlist');

              })();
          }
       });
   }
});

});
```

but when click on each `<li>` in `<ul id="qlist">` the result in alert is the last row of data in my database and same for all the li tags in list. it seems self invoking is not working .

My Actions if needed:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetQuestion(int id)
    {
        var ajaxq = db.Questions.Where(e => e.SubCategoryId == id).Select(e => new
        {
            quest=e.Qu,
            answe=e.Ans
        }).ToList();

        return Json(ajaxq);
    }
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetSubCat(int? id)
    {
        //:TODO
        if (id == null)
        {
            //return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }


        var result = db.SubCategories.Where(e => e.CategoryId == id).Select(e => new
        {
            scat = e.SubCategoryName,
            scatid = e.Id

        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Closures.  When your click event fires, `helpquestion` is no longer what it was.

Comment: thanks.I'm sorry I forgot it's name (Closures) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your event handler to look at the current item rather than try to hold on to some variable:

```
$('<li/>').html("<p>" + helpquestion.quest + "</p>")
    .click(function () {

            alert($(this).text())

    }).appendTo('#qlist');
```

Comment: thanks thanks it solved. I Find the problem by your help in comment,thank u 1000 times.just a little question.does this way have a bad performance?

Comment: Using `$(this).` has zero impact (probably less impact as it doesn't need to remember the data).  It's on a `click` event, so not time-critical (you're not running it 10mill times).   You could improve efficiency by using an event delegate, then you only need to have a single click handler instead of one per question - or event just assign the handler after appending all the questions would be better (and why you would use `$(this)`)

Comment: really thank you.I should implement you'r suggestions as soos as possible .thank you.now it has less than 100 questions so I don't think that its that much urgent right now. about `this`   in the question if you mean it solved like this : `var test = helpquestion;`  then in click `alert(test.answe);` then it works fine

Comment: "does this way have bad performance" - I see no reason you'd use a self-executing-function (or "Immediately Invoked Function Expression" IIFE) here.  It just makes the code confusing.  I assumed this was some sample code for the question.

Comment: you mean I need to change the way I implement this question list?now it works fine but thanks I will work more on it to find a better solution

Comment: I mean: if you remove `(function () {` and matching `})();` it should work exactly the same.